# Is it $\Leftrightarrow$ or just $\Rightarrow$?

Tags: calculus

Is it $$|x| \leq a \Leftrightarrow -a \leq x \leq a$$ or just $$|x| \leq a \Rightarrow -a \leq x \leq a$$ ?

Comment: it's $\iff$       :-)

Comment: What do *you* think? Why?

Comment: It's equivalence. The two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Both :) ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

It is iff. Practically speaking, with $\iff$ you can reach either side of $\iff$ without doing any illegal steps, meaning you can go backwards.

So you have

$|x|\leq a \implies -a \leq x \leq a$
and
$-a \leq x \leq a \implies |x|\leq a$
Which means you go backwards, thus $\iff$ can be used.

$\iff$ implies $\implies$, but only if you can use $\implies$ both ways you can use a $\iff$. Which means that it would be correct to use $\implies$ instead of $\iff$ in some cases where you have no reason to be able to reach from your end result to your first implication, but in general, mathematicians prefer to be strict and use $\iff$ when applicable. As far as physicists are concerned, most of them tend to prefer $\implies$ on proofs as they don't have to check if they can use $\iff$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would easily be able to prove that it is $\iff$.  Here, I will help you, and you will see that it was not hard to think about at all.

> Let's first show that if $x$ satisfies $|x| \leq a$ for some $a \geq 0$, then $x$ satisfies $-a \leq x \leq a$.

What does it mean for $x$ to satisfy $|x| \leq a$?  It means if $x$ is positive, then it is less than or equal to $a$, and if $x$ is negative, the positive version of $x$ is less than or equal to $a$ (or, $-a \leq x$).  But it is not hard to see that this describes all of the numbers between $-a$ and $a$, so $x$ satisfies $-a \leq x \leq a$.

> Now let's try to show the opposite direction:

Suppose we know that for some $a \geq 0$, $x$ satisfies $-a \leq x \leq a$.  That means if $x$ is positive then $x = |x|$, and so $|x| \leq a$.  Similarly, if $x$ is negative but *bigger* than $-a$, then the positive version of $x$ (which is $|x|$) is *smaller* than $a$.  So, in every case, $|x| \leq a$.

I hope that gives you some intuition for why it is $\iff$.